# How to use combined unicode characters in android keyboard?

Tags: java, android, unicode, keyboard

I am trying to create a keyboard in my native language but I am facing a problem. In my language there are letters which are combination of other letters.ক্ষ = u0995+u09CD +u09B7 how to use it in my keyboard.

```
 <Key android:keyOutputText="0x0995" android:keyLabel="ক্ষ"/>
```

For example I used:

```
<Key android:codes="0x09DC" android:keyLabel="ড়"/>
    <Key android:codes="0x09DD" android:keyLabel="ঢ়"/>
    <Key android:codes="0x09DF" android:keyLabel="য়"/>
    <Key android:codes="0x09CE" android:keyLabel="ৎ"/>
    <Key android:codes="0x098B" android:keyLabel="ঋ"/>
```

So how to combine unicode characters and use it in android studio ?